# If I buy a Ubisoft game on Steam, can I play the game through Uplay?

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect, assassins-creed-unity

I just bought Assassin's Creed Unity on Steam, but the place I was playing can't install the game on Steam but the game is already installed in Uplay, can I play the game from Uplay instead of from Steam?

Comment: Why can't you install the game through Steam? Do you have insufficient space? Do you own the game on both Uplay and Steam? Do you mean you want to play the Steam version through Uplay? The last is certainly not possible.

Comment: The reason you want to do this is important . I have not tried it but i own R6 Siege on Steam . When i lunch it , steam automatically opens uplay first then through uplay the game launches automatically (since it was launched by steam) but i would assume if you do it the first time you could then launch it through uplay . But you didn't specify the fact that you own the game on uplay too or not? If you do then i'm afraid steam can't link it's own copy of the game to your uplay account. You might need to create a 2nd uplay account to link your steam version . Try to explain the situation a bit.

Comment: Although your explanation is wrong . We don't use "place" in the digital world . It's either the drive you are trying to install or the system you are trying to install it on.

Comment: If the game's already installed, what's stopping you from just trying?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** assuming you've launched the game once, when you first launch a Ubisoft game that requires uPlay from Steam uPlay should be installed with it, an account must be created (or logged into), then uPlay will ask you if you're sure you want to **link the game key** to your account before you can play through just uPlay.

Once that is done you should be able to sign on just uPlay remotely and play at a friends house etc

**You'll see a screen like this if it works but for Assassins Creed**
[image: Starting game, this will bind the following products to your Ubisoft Account, <UserName> For Honor - Starter Edition]

Comment: "I just bought Assassin's Creed Unity on Steam" yes, but linking it to uPlay as detailed here or on uPlay lets you play it through just uPlay (I can launch Rainbow Six: Siege despite only buying it on Steam)

Linking the *game key* is what adds it to your account on uPlay.

Comment: I've amended it to the final one line as requested. The uPlay FAQ does **not** comment on what I meant. My mistake, but I assure you there is a prompt asking if you want to associate this game key with this account.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I added a preview of the screen that appears for For Honor that I bought during the Holiday event on steam. (still haven't played lol)